# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined . someone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, requirejs

HTML file:

```
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

javascript file:

```
const axios = require("axios")

async function handlecep(){
    const uf = await axios.get("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados")
    const response = await fetch(uf)
    const data = await response.jso(response)
    console.log(data)
}
handlecep()
```

Comment: Hi, out of the box `require` only works in node.js, for browsers you need a library that implements it.

Comment: You could use https://browserify.org/ to help `require` packages/libraries.

Comment: Doesn't work cause you have a typo. There should be a `reponse.json` instead of `response.jso`.

Answer (score 1):

The `require` function isn't natively supported by browsers.  Assuming you have Axios installed(`npm i axios`), you put this above your `<script src="./index.js"></script>` tag:

```html
<script src="node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

And use Axios from there, without using `require`:

```js
async function handlecep() {
    const uf = await axios.get("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados");
    const response = await fetch(uf);
    const data = await response.jso(response);
    console.log(data);
}
handlecep();
```